# Yii2 validation with XRegExp, \p{L} not working

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-validation, xregexp

I'm using Yii2 framework and I have a `Validator` that should do client-side validation. I have a regex that looks like this: `/^[\\p{L}]+$/u` for simplicity, but my actual regex is a bit more complicated, but the \p{L} part is what causes the problems.

And so my code like this in the validator class:

```
public function clientValidateAttribute($model, $attribute, $view)
{
    $message = json_encode($this->message, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    return <<<JS
    if (!XRegExp('/^[\\p{L}]+$/u').test(value)) {
        messages.push($message);
    }
JS;
}
```

Problem is, this always fails for \p{L} but if I change the pattern for something like /^[A-Z]+$/ it works flawlessly.

I'm using the 1.3.0 xregexp-all.js. It is added to in an `AssetBundle` class in \assets\AppAsset.php

Comment: what is `\p`, I have not seen before in regex

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad " \p{L} or \p{Letter}: any kind of letter from any language. ". Source: [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: what actually you want to do?

Comment: I want to have the unicode stuff like the \p{L} available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did notice while I was playing around with my regex, that when I made it wrong and was shown an exception, `\\p{L}` was interpreted as `p{L}`. So after some tries I've found out that for whatever reason I needed four backslashes to get it interpreted as `\p{L}`. Final code that works:

```
public function clientValidateAttribute($model, $attribute, $view)
{
    $message = json_encode($this->message, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    return <<<JS
    if(!XRegExp('^[\\\\p{L}]+$').test(value)) {
        messages.push($message);
    }
JS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `\p{L}` was interpreted as `p{L}` so I just added a backslash to escape `p` and the result is `\\p{L}`.